# Update statement to move wrong values to correct column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a situation in PL/SQL where I have a table called 'Gender' which has 2 Columns `GENDER1` and `GENDER2`.
Column `GENDER1` is supposed to have only males - value -M and `GENDER2` is supposed to only have female values -F.
For what ever reason there are some F values in column `GENDER1` and there are some M values in column `GENDER2`.

Is there a way that I could in a single `Update` statement have the values moved to their respective correct columns?

Comment: Why are you storing gender in two columns?

Comment: By "have the values moved" in a single update, are you intending to update the correct column, and clear out the incorrect column value as well?

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for you prompt response! I was asked this question in an interview and i told them that i would do it in TWO update statements. Only afterwards did i realize my faux pas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this update statement does what you are asking:

```
update gender
    set gender1 = (case when gender2 = 'M' then 'M' else gender1 end),
        gender2 = (case when gender1 = 'F' then 'F' else gender2 end)
    where gender1 = 'F' or gender2 = 'M';
```

However, I don't understand what the data structure is trying to represent.